# 1996 Suzuki Sidekick engine

Tags: suzuki, crank-position-sensor

I blew up my motor in my 1996 Suzuki Sidekick; I installed a donor motor from a 1996 Suzuki (both engines looked alike, each a 16 valve engine).  It turns out the crank sensor on my original engine is located in the pan at the front of the engine; the donor engine has the crank sensor located on the transmission.  My question is, what is required to make the donor engine look like the original engine with the crank sensor located at the front of the engine (is the block of the donor engine machined such that it can accept the crank sensor from the blown engine and would I need any other parts off the blown engine; I have a new pan for the donor engine)??

Comment: @SolarMike - It seems you are being intentionally obtuse. The OP is asking: *Can the crankshaft position sensor be relocated from the transmission to the block; is there already a provision for it?* ...

Comment: @solarmike - Perhaps realizing there might be a language barrier would help as well.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I was going to ask if the position of the sensor was at the same angle to the crank so it does not matter if it changes position but you have taken this in a direction that does not focus on solving the problem so I am staying away from now.

Comment: I think this depends more on where the reluctor is on the crank itself. I’m sure you could relocate the sensor, but it might make more sense to extend the harness to the new sensor location.

Comment: @Ben - I think the problem lies in the fact the OP has only changed out the engine and not the transmission. If the transmission does not have a provision in the sensor, extending the sensor harness won't do them any good. It seems the OP may be stuck between a rock & a hard place here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 true. It’d help if we knew exactly which engine op had and what the donor engine is if it has a vin plate on it.

Comment: I am the OP.  The original engine is an SOHC.  I don't know what the donor engine is.  I do have the tranny from the donor car and perhaps my sensor harness would reach the tranny if I were to change it out.  I was hoping someone would know if the donor engine block was machined to accept the crank sensor; I will have to pull the donor oil pan off and look for myself.  Thanks for your help.